# Calculator: exception with decimal numbers

Tags: c#, xaml, decimal, calculator

It works to add,subtract,multiply and divide with integers, but not with decimal numbers.
It is something wrong with sum1 variables, like they are in the wrong format when a decimal is asigned too them. It's because they are declated as double, BUT I don't know how to write it differently.

```
double sum1 = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    bool plusButtonClicked = false;
    bool subButtonClicked = false;
    bool multButtonClicked = false;
    bool divButtonClicked = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
        e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
    }

    private void one_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numEnt.Text += one.Content;
    }

    private void two_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numEnt.Text += two.Content;
    }

    private void three_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numEnt.Text += three.Content;
    }

    private void four_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numEnt.Text += four.Content;
    }

    private void five_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numEnt.Text += five.Content;
    }

    private void six_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numEnt.Text += six.Content;
    }

    private void seven_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numEnt.Text += seven.Content;
    }

    private void eight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numEnt.Text += eight.Content;
    }

    private void nine_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numEnt.Text += nine.Content;
    }

    private void zero_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numEnt.Text += zero.Content;
    }

    private void add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sum1 += double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
        numEnt.Clear();

        plusButtonClicked = true;
        subButtonClicked = false;
        multButtonClicked = false;
        divButtonClicked = false;
    }

    private void sub_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sum1 += double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
        numEnt.Clear();

        plusButtonClicked = false;
        subButtonClicked = true;
        multButtonClicked = false;
        divButtonClicked = false;
    }

    private void mult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sum1 += double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
        numEnt.Clear();

        plusButtonClicked = false;
        subButtonClicked = false;
        multButtonClicked = true;
        divButtonClicked = false;
    }

    private void div_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sum1 += double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
        numEnt.Clear();

        plusButtonClicked = false;
        subButtonClicked = false;
        multButtonClicked = false;
        divButtonClicked = true;
    }

    private void deci_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string currentInput = numEnt.Text;
        bool pointFound = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < currentInput.Length; i++)
        {
            if (currentInput[i] == '.')
                pointFound = true;

        }

        if (pointFound == false)
            numEnt.Text += ".";
    }

    private void equal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (plusButtonClicked == true)
        {
            sum2 = sum1 + double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
            result.Text = sum2.ToString();
            sum1 = 0;
        }

        if (subButtonClicked == true)
        {
            sum2 = sum1 - double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
            result.Text = sum2.ToString();
            sum1 = 0;
        }

        if (multButtonClicked == true)
        {
            sum2 = sum1 * double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
            result.Text = sum2.ToString();
            sum1 = 0;
        }

        if (divButtonClicked == true)
        {
            sum2 = sum1 / double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
            result.Text = sum2.ToString();
            sum1 = 0;
        }
    }

    private void clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        numEnt.Clear();
        calculations.Clear();
        result.Clear();
    }




}
```

Comment: What is the exception exactly? On which line? What is the value of `numEnt.Text` ?

Comment: I really can't understand this code. You're adding the number to sum1 regardless of whether it's add, subtract, multi or div ?

Comment: what is the type of `Sum1`?? if it's declared as `Integer` then you wouldn't be able to get numbers with `Decimal`

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare your `sum1` variable as `double`. And one more thing you need a `for loop` to check whether a string have a `decimal point`. Instead you can use `string.Contains` method. try this code hope it will help

```
double sum1 =0.0 ;
private void add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sum1 += double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
    numEnt.Clear();

    plusButtonClicked = true;
    subButtonClicked = false;
    multButtonClicked = false;
    divButtonClicked = false;
}

private void sub_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sum1 -= double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
    numEnt.Clear();

    plusButtonClicked = false;
    subButtonClicked = true;
    multButtonClicked = false;
    divButtonClicked = false;
}

private void mult_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sum1 *= double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
    numEnt.Clear();

    plusButtonClicked = false;
    subButtonClicked = false;
    multButtonClicked = true;
    divButtonClicked = false;
}

private void div_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sum1 /= double.Parse(numEnt.Text);
    numEnt.Clear();

    plusButtonClicked = false;
    subButtonClicked = false;
    multButtonClicked = false;
    divButtonClicked = true;
}

private void deci_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string currentInput = numEnt.Text;
    bool pointFound = false;

    //for (int i = 0; i < currentInput.Length; i++)
    //{
        if(currentInput.Contains("."))//if (currentInput[i] == '.')
            pointFound = true;

    //}

    if (pointFound == false)
        numEnt.Text += ".";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably dot is not your decimal separator. In this case you can use

```
 double.Parse(string, IFormatProvider)
```

to set the decimal separator you want.

try this

```
var currentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture;
var numberFormat = (System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo) currentCultur .NumberFormat.Clone();
numberFormat .NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
```

sum1 += double.Parse(numEnt.Text, numberFormat );

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure how to implement that in the code. I don't get any errors but if it's not too much trouble, could you please write it in my code and post it?